# how to apply a mask to an item coming from an API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, backend

I have a basic CRUD situation, where in the form, when I send the data, it inserts the mask normally, and when sending it to my local API, I format it and leave it in numeric format. But how am I going to apply the mask again on the item being displayed in a grid?

in my form, is like this

[image]

and on the grid, it displays like this

[image]

now, I need to apply the mask again, but on the grid that is showing. How to make?

to show the items on the grid, I am doing this via Javascript:

```
const exibirEmpresas = (u) => {
  Array.from(u).forEach((lista) => {
    dadosEmpresa += `
        <tr>
        <td class="idEmp" id="idEmp">${lista.idEmpresa}</td>
        <td class="nomeEmp">${lista.nomeEmpresa}</td>
        <td class="emailCad">${lista.email}</td>
        <td class="cnpjCad" id="cnpjList">${lista.cnpj}</td>
        <td class="dataCadastroCad">${lista.dataCadastro}</td>
        <td class="dataAtualizacaoCad">${lista.dataAtualizacao}</td>
        <td>
          <button id="atualiza-empresa" onclick="editItem(${lista.idEmpresa})">Editar</button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="deletebtn" onclick="removeItem(${lista.idEmpresa})">Excluir</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
        `;
  });
  listaEmpresa.innerHTML = dadosEmpresa;
};

// GET

fetch(urlAPI)
  .then((s) => s.json())
  .then((dados) => exibirEmpresas(dados));
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code/HTML that you have now (but not more), including the code that currently puts the value in the grid.

Comment: I edited the post now, put the code that is showing the values ​​in the grid.

Comment: Thanks (BTW, this is not a blog). When exactly should that reformatting happen : on load of the page (immediately), or on an event, like a click on one of the buttons?

Comment: should happen when loading the grid page, because there are more values, so it would have to be applied to all automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are essentially looking for a way to turn a 14-digit string like "19879847984784" to "19.879.847/9847-84".

You can add this JavaScript code to your script. The HTML is just an example with hard coded values.

```js
function formatCnpj() {
    for (let td of document.querySelectorAll(".cnpjCad")) {
        td.textContent = td.textContent
               .replace(/\D/g, "")
               .replace(/(..)(...)(...)(....)/, "$1.$2.$3/$4-");
    }
}

formatCnpj();
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td, th { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="idEmp" id="idEmp">28</td>
    <td class="nomeEmp">John Larkin</td>
    <td class="emailCad">john.larkin@x.com</td>
    <td class="cnpjCad" id="cnpjList">19961423596110</td>
    <td class="dataCadastroCad">2000-09-09</td>
    <td class="dataAtualizacaoCad">2020-09-09</td>
    <td>
      <button id="atualiza-empresa" onclick="editItem(${lista.idEmpresa})">Editar</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="deletebtn" onclick="removeItem(${lista.idEmpresa})">Excluir</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="idEmp" id="idEmp">12</td>
    <td class="nomeEmp">Helene Park</td>
    <td class="emailCad">helene.park@n.com</td>
    <td class="cnpjCad" id="cnpjList">19879847984784</td>
    <td class="dataCadastroCad">2000-01-01</td>
    <td class="dataAtualizacaoCad">2020-01-01</td>
    <td>
      <button id="atualiza-empresa" onclick="editItem(${lista.idEmpresa})">Editar</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="deletebtn" onclick="removeItem(${lista.idEmpresa})">Excluir</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in my case, it's not working because the item is coming from an local api and I'm doing an interpolation in HTML, and when you call a querySelectorAll() in a function, passing  the id or a class, it returns an empty NodeList array.

Comment: Make sure to call the function `formatCnpj` when the interpolation has completed. Your question does not include any information on how you call that API or do the interpolation, nor attempt, so we're left guessing. Possibly if is enough to do `window.addEventListener("load", formatCnpj);`.